# How to select count with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to show the amount of data stored on the database tables using
Laravel v 4.2.0  but i have a problem with using function count(). here's my code :

```
$total = DB::select("select count(*) from rents left join operators on operators.code = rents.code where (operators.code is null) and rents.booking = 'N'");    
echo $total;
```

the message error say :

```
Syntax error or access violation
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$total = DB::select(DB::raw("select count(*) as cnt from rents left join operators on operators.code = rents.code where (operators.code is null) and rents.booking = 'N'"));    
echo $total[0]->cnt;
```

Try Debugging:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($total);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: Is your SQL Query fetching result for you?

Comment: I have edited my answer, try debugging and see what output you are getting, as well as append that output to the question.